# I am not able to mock the Dao method using mockito in Spring boot application

Tags: java, spring-boot, mockito, integration-testing, junit4

I am not able to mock Dao method in spring boot. Please let me know what I am doing wrong in below code.
I tried using SpringJUnit4ClassRunner and mock the Dao method. But still, it's going into the Dao method instead of returning the mock value.
I also tried with MockitoJUnitRunner but that time not able to call the service method as its getting null value.

```
@RestController
public class HomeController {

    @Autowired
    HomeSeriveInterface service;

    @Autowired
    HomeDaoImpl homeDao;

    @GetMapping(value="/getData")
    public String Data() {
        System.out.println("Inside Controller");
        List < Map < String, Object >> rows = service.getData();
        return "Hi Yogita" + rows;
    }

}

@Service
public class HomeService implements HomeSeriveInterface{

    @Autowired
    HomeDao dao;

    @Override
    public List<Map<String, Object>> getData() {
        System.out.println("Inside Service");
        return dao.getData();
    }

}

@Repository
public class HomeDaoImpl implements HomeDao{

    @Autowired
     @Qualifier("jdbcTemplate1")
     private JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate;

    @Override
    public List < Map < String, Object >> getData() {
        System.out.println("Inside Dao");
        List < Map < String, Object >> rows = jdbcTemplate.queryForList("SELECT * FROM COURCES");
        return rows;
    }

}

@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest
public class CcdWebApplicationTests {


    @InjectMocks
    @Autowired
    HomeController homeController;

    @Mock
    HomeDao homeDao;

    @Before
    public void init() {
        MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this);
    }

    @Test
    public void getDataTest() {
        System.out.println("testing *******");
        List < Map < String, Object >> data = null;
        Mockito.when(homeDao.getData())
        .thenReturn(data);
        System.out.println("2nd *");
        String data2 = homeController.Data();
        System.out.println(data2);

    }

}
```

Comment: The controller doesn't use the DAO. It uses a HomeSeriveInterface. That's what you should mock to test the controller. Not the DAO that it doesn't use. Also, you don't need Spring at all in a pure unit test like this. Remove the all the Spring annotations from the test class and fields.

Comment: Thanks @JBNizet but I want to call Dao methods also. What should I do for calling the full controller flow, means Controller->Service->Dao->Serive->Dao.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need `@InjectMocks` and use `@MockBean` instead of `@Mock`:

```
@Autowired
HomeController homeController;

@MockBean
HomeDao homeDao;
```

You also **do not** need this part:

```
@Before
public void init() {
    MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this);
}
```

Comment: I tried this but HomeDao is @Repository that's why I can't use MockBean, It's giving error "Bean could not be found"

Comment: @Repository is adding a Bean to the context eventually just like Service and Controller

Comment: Yes your solution work for me. I use @MockBean for HomeDaoImpl instead of HomeDao and it gives me expected output. Thank you.

Comment: I have a similar issue, but I am not using Spring boot, @MockBean is a Spring boot annotation, is there any equivalent for Spring JUnits?